# Is there a way to extract the last element(s), with type, from a union of tuples of different length?

Tags: typescript

I've put an example [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAKgRhgXhgbQHYFcC2AjKAJwBoYBnEQgSwwHNTt8i0BdFgblEljgCYV0jAiRhCipCtToNcw1hy7R4AZgGZZ40RpFiRkmvS1NC8zotgAZAIYUAogBsoOKBhBkA8gDMAPMBjwYKAAPEBcAEzIYQigrMIB7DHswdCwMAGsMOIB3DFJUjOzcmAA6UvzMnPlgAD4BOECQ8Mjo2ISk9FLi8sLWUhpPIhgAQT6MAcIYACEWPxgAfnQRqZn-AC5RKAA3IjNPVIBjECoEmE8rKnsyAH0rECuQAAsoK-D7wjArhAAKK0JadcQMAAPvB+CC4MoAJQwdbWOyOZyuDw+cDQOKeGC-Wi1ADes2iICwhAwmL+xTI9io+ygXwAtLxIZwAL7AYB7DCHY4ks4Xa63e5PF4YMJvD68H5-AFIcFglTQ9ZofTSIxyNgwPH+AlEkloLG6smOOiPeksUh6rHFQ20Y0INjM1nszknKh3LJxQhpPl3R7PCi-EAS-6g4FymGCbQyYwsdX4qCE4noPUABlNpNoaFtChZbIORxOFKpzx5lxe2wwN29gr9hADWIBsoh8vDxkjwmjGqice1afJlOpXyTpAZzKAA).

I have a number of tuples of different lengths that all end with the same sequence of types.

```
type T1 = [number, string, number[]];
type T2 = [number, number, string, number[]];
type T3 = [number, number, number, string, number[]];
```

Given an object that's a union of those types, I know the type of the last element(s), and I can even get typescript to deduce those types for me, but I can't find a way to get typescript to figure it out when I extract an element from the tuple:

```
function doesnt_work(arg: T1|T2|T3) : [string, number[]] {
  return [arg[arg.length-2], arg[arg.length-1]];
}
```

Note that ts does know that arg[0] has type number, and arg[1] has type number|string. I'm hoping to find a way to have it figure out the type of `arg[arg.length-1]` (or arg.pop(), or arg.slice(-1) etc).

I tried `arg[arg.length-n]`, `arg.slice(-n)`, `arg.pop()` etc.

I was hoping that typescript would infer the type, since it knows what the type of the last element of the tuple is. But it just infers the type as if I'd indexed the tuple with an unknown number.

Comment: What you're asking for is not currently supported in TypeScript and might not be supported anytime soon. See [ms/TS#47660](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47660) where this sort of thing for `at()` was declined as too complex. An [unholy approach](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47660#issuecomment-1025054467) is possible, as shown in [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/N9VB9m), but I doubt it's worth the effort or dealing with edge cases. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thats pretty much what I thought, but was hoping there was a clever way to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't currently give strong types for *relative* indexing into [tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types).
There is such a thing as [leading rest elements in tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-2.html#leadingmiddle-rest-elements-in-tuple-types) like `[...unknown[], string, number[]]`, but this just makes it easy to represent a supertype of `T1 | T2 | T3`; it doesn't give you strong typings for `arg[arg.length - 2]`.  It's more helpful to *callers* of your function than to the *implementation*.

You don't get a strong type from `arg[arg.length - 2]` because the type of `arg.length - 2` is just `number`; there is no built-in support for type-level manipulation of numeric [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types), as requested in longstanding open issue [microsoft/TypeScript#26382](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26382).  Even if that changes someday, having `T1 | T2 | T3` be a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) would still probably do bad things, since `arg.length - 2` would be evaluated as `1 | 2 | 3` which would be uncorrelated to the type of `arg` (see [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581)).  So that's probably a dead end.

---

There was a feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#47660](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47660) to give strong types when calling [the `at()` array method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at) with negative indices, but it was declined as "too complex".

And while you could *try* to do so yourself, the lack of support for numeric literal type arithmetic means you have to jump through some ugly hoops, as shown [in this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47660#issuecomment-1025054467):

```
type Reverse<T extends readonly any[], U extends any[] = []> =
  T extends readonly [infer F, ...infer R] ? Reverse<R, [F, ...U]> : U

type At<T extends readonly any[], I extends number> =
  `${I}` extends `-${infer J}` ? [never, ...Reverse<T>] extends
  infer R ? J extends keyof R ? R[J] :
  undefined : never : T[I]

interface ReadonlyArray<T> {
  at<I extends number>(index: I): At<this, I>;
}
interface Array<T> {
  at<I extends number>(index: I): At<this, I>;
}
```

which works for your example code:

```
function f(arg: T1 | T2 | T3): [string, number[]] {
  const penultimate = arg.at(-2) // string
  const ultimate = arg.at(-1) // number[]
  return [penultimate, ultimate]; // okay
}
```

but is probably more trouble than it's worth, especially since there are undoubtedly many edge cases and you'd have to maintain it yourself.  If the TS team thinks it's too complex to provide in the native TS library, you should probably avoid doing so for your own code base unless you have a very good reason.

---

So it's not currently possible in TypeScript, at least for now.  You might as well just use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) like `arg[arg.length-2] as string` and `arg[arg.length-1] as number[]` and move on.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBASlAblATgZygHgCoygDxCgDsATNGFKAQ1IHtiAbMGa4sAbQF0AaGAVTyES5Vu24wAvDG4A+KcBgxcBImQpVaDZjICWxAGaoYAMT4A6S-qMp4XGAH54SVBkxw+HMzEvn+XeQAuAWBQSFgAQRAcITVRTXomFjZOXhgASViRCmIAVwBbACNUeUlFGAADABIAb3SAXwqs9UqAWlrrYwApRscZYhcUC0sEZHQsbFl7VWzyzts4Pq7m0QBrKDA6A3g+uA4u+0Dy3LIoA30oUhhggbHr5Q50rlD9IhQDagBjWAQtJIiUChqGAcPIauVqNFMjMWnkiiUABT6UgEYLpACUwSimBAAAtdGg+OlZABuYD1YCvVAfb4wAFAkGTGDgpSQzDQ4SwgrFFCyJGnfBozF06J4glE0nk0JhaDKACMUn63NQfDQIBQ+gA5nw4TzuFwyeBZdgAEyKji6lUwS1DGBqjXEbXW5UofWG8LKADM5ptOpdfvhtvtWoDeq4BulBhOnxAugYMAMCOoKE1wWwCoAPsozVnsJ7hRxg47Q6h9czyp8GGqYNA8oxY-lIbBpMnNeZIQjWib0TAAPS9u3qrUVqsgGC5eu6RtERWt9sgTtynv952B7jlKggXIoYgyWsThtNvgHqdNg19gd0VbAqWhIA)

Answer (score 1):

Since [Union Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) contain a finite amount of different types you could narrow down that type using `if`s or a `switch` statement:

```
type T1 = [number, string, number[]];
type T2 = [number, number, string, number[]];
type T3 = [number, number, number, string, number[]];

function works(arg: T1 | T2 | T3): [string, number[]] {
  switch (arg.length) {
    case 3:
      return [arg[1], arg[2]];
    case 4:
      return [arg[2], arg[3]];
    case 5:
      return [arg[3], arg[4]];
    default:
      throw new Error("Invalid tuple type");
  }
}
```

If you're willing to alter your function declaration you could change the parameter type to `[...any, string, number[]]` to define [rest elements](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-2.html#leadingmiddle-rest-elements-in-tuple-types). `T1`, `T2` and `T3` all `extend` that type. That way TypeScript is able to infer the last elements.

```
type T1 = [number, string, number[]];
type T2 = [number, number, string, number[]];
type T3 = [number, number, number, string, number[]];

function works2(arg: [...any, string, number[]]): [string, number[]] {
  return [arg[arg.length - 2], arg[arg.length - 1]];
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgjFAvFA2gOwK4FsBGEBOANFAM7D4CWaA5sZrgSgLpMDcAUKJLAExKr08RKIILEylGnWxDmbTuGgwAzP3QyxIjcNHCJVWlob45HdgDMMaAMbAKAezRQA7vfwBrEgAoAhvmoAXLAIAD68UGEqAJRBKPpSRrIsUADe7FCkzhTA1gAWUL7+AHQANhA0wLlRqekZUNY+JNDKAbV1UPgQwBj4Tih+1ChwTMQDKDwsHO0NTVAALK3tGZ3dvahjE6P+KMqTbfWN0ACsi0srPX1ju1uDc3vtACYQ5j4YJcCn7ZX49s4iEH8AKL4H74LwAIgAkmgAG4+EoUB5QbpgMrIxTgqJTKAAX3YeIsVlsDicrg8JB4hUCqCKtJ8aBA4nIBmkxjkMVQ8UMujkNWWXQu622A1K5WolSgAFooJsoGMRWUKvlpcN5DigA)

Comment: You might want to link to the documentation for [leading rest elements in tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-2.html#leadingmiddle-rest-elements-in-tuple-types)

Comment: Thanks, but `works` is exactly what I'm trying to avoid. And `works2` doesn't really work; it's no different from `arg: any[]`. See [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgjFAvFA2gOwK4FsBGEBOANFAM7D4CWaA5sZrgSgLpMDcAUKJLAExKr08RKIILEylGnWxDmbTuGgwAzP3QyxIjcNHCJVWlob45HduwBmGNAGNgFAPZooAEwcQSaYAH18EAIYANoEg3gDuDvgA1gAU-vjUAFyoAHRp-mgg4uQG0sZyAJRQAN7sUFA48TEo8dQ1CSmBEDTAABZQALRQPEzEtfXUjc3UbZ1QcCwFHAC+5la29k4VVbXJ6sbZknWTJezTQA). I need the call to bar to be an error.